# Having difficulty removing nipple from gas valve

Tags: gas, valve, range

I'm trying to replace a gas range and hook up the new flex line, but I haven't been able to get the old nipple out of the valve. I've tried using a nipple extractor but haven't had any luck.

I'm curious whether this threaded piece is actually part of the valve and not a nipple, and/or whether I should just have the entire valve replaced (likely by a professional). Any thoughts here would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It looks like someone tried a pipe wrench on the nipple, presumably with a wrench on the valve body to restrain it. Do you have access to the pipe below the valve if replacing the valve is necessary? It looks like it has had a hard life.

Comment: Until you clean the interface between the nipple and valve to be sure, then I think it is one piece. Then get it replaced.